# Is boundary of a subspace strictly less dimensional then space in topology

Tags: general-topology

Answering this you just save my time and health. It is very bad question by  itself but very easy to answer I think.

In topology the boundary of a set $S$ is the set of points in the closure of $S$ not belonging to the interior of $S$.

Is it true that if dimension of a space is defined then boundary is strictly less dimensional?

I was thinking so, but stuck on the case of plane and line.

I used to think that a line on a plane has empty boundary (or segment has endpoints as boundary) but now stuck ...

Consider a plane $\mathbb R^2$ with euclidean topology and a line $l$.

Let $x\in l$. Arbitrary ball $B(x,r)$ with $r>0$ intersects complement of a line and hence interior of $l$ is empty (am I wrong here?).

Since $l$ is closed (every point of a complement has a ball separeting it from the line) then $cl(l)\setminus int(l)=l$.

What do I wrong? :O

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking for the boundary of the entire space? Or the boundary of a closed subspace? Or the boundary of an arbitrary subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea has led to one of the simplests concepts to define a topological dimension, the [small inductive dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension) $\operatorname{ind}(X)$ of a topological space. We say that a space has $\operatorname{ind}(X) \le n$ iff $X$ has a base $\mathcal{B}$ (of open sets) such that $\operatorname{ind}(U) \le n-1$ for all $U \in \mathcal{B}$.

To start the induction, one defines $\operatorname{ind}(\emptyset)=-1$, so a space has small inductive dimension $\le 0$ if it has a base with clopen (closed-and-open) sets (these are exactly the sets with empty boundary), and includes spaces like $\Bbb Q$ and the irrationals.

To finish off the definition $\operatorname{ind}(X) =n$ is precisely when $\operatorname{ind}(X) \le n$ holds and $\operatorname{ind}(X) \le n-1$ fails.

There are other inductive ways to define dimension function, like the large inductive dimension $\operatorname{Ind}(X)$, and the (Lebesgue) covering dimension   $\dim(X)$, and the Brouwer "Dimensionsgrad" (fallen out of use, but of historic importance).

For separable metric spaces (like $\Bbb R^n$ and most manifolds, like spheres etc.)  these notions all give the same values and agree that the value on $\Bbb R^n$ is $n$ (but this is quite hard to prove, mind you).

So in some sense it's true (by definition of dimension, plus some theorems), but only for boundaries of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

The boundary of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb R$!

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample take the Cantor set. It, and every nonempty subset of it, is $0$-dimensional. It does have a certain nonempty subsets whose boundary is empty, i.e. $-1$-dimensional, for example the clopen subsets. Nonetheless many subsets have nonempty boundary, which gives lots of $0$-dimensional subsets with $0$-dimensional boundary; and this includes many open subsets.

Comment: What do you mean by 0-dimensional?

Comment: Yes it is reasonable that Cantor is 0-dim it has basis of clopens. That is my bad belief that boundary is less dimensional. And remaining is true? :)

Comment: Pick your favorite topologically invariant definition of dimension. [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) is particularly simple to verify: every open cover has a refinement into pairwise disjoint open sets.

Comment: The boundaries of clopen sets are  $\emptyset$ which has dimension $-1$ so there also it holds. (looking at the boundary as a subset of $C$ not in $\Bbb R$). @EvgenyKuznetsov

Comment: Edited to fix my error asserting "every" subset to be a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the notions of "a topological space" and "a subspace of a topological space".

The line, homoemorphic to $\Bbb{R}$, taken as a topological space, has no boundary.  It does not float in some enclosing space.  Open balls in the line are open intervals.

However, if we think of the line as a subspace of the plane, inheriting the subspace topology (by intersections of the line with open set of the plane), we find that every point of the line-in-the-plane is a boundary point.

The difference is the existence of the ambient space and whose open sets we are taking to define our topology.